# how to create a view in SQL creating an alias for the column names ?

Tags: sql

I not find a way to create a view so that you can change the column names of the original structure of the table for a more "friendly" alias.

thanks

Comment: Google:  "<your database name> create view".

Comment: SELECT <columnName> <aliasName>

Comment: `create view viewname (newcol1, newcol2, ...) as select col1, col2, ...`

Answer (score 4):

In most DBMS you can use the "AS" keyword in the SELECT statement:

```
CREATE VIEW myView AS (
  SELECT 
    id AS friendly_id,
    value AS friendly_value
  FROM table
);
```

Comment: Just tested it, also works in Oracle! Thank you :-)